# Running builds on a specific, dedicated node set

Tags: openshift-origin

Is it possible to write a scheduler rule to schedule builds on a specific node label (e.g. `role=builder`)? I'm struggling to understand how the schedular rules match pod labels (e.g. `buildconfig=web` to node types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible today without adding a custom scheduler extension.  The has been discussion about adding it, but no work has been done so far.